# How to replace only SOME column values in dataframe taking them from another on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames in pandas(python)

```
df1
UniqueKey ValueFix ValueChange
A           10        100
B           15        0
C           20        150
D           15        0
E           10        100

df2
UniqueKey ValueFix ValueChange
B           15        300
D           15        400
```

I want to update df1 based on values from df2 BUT **update only values in column 'Value Change'**. Because in reality I **should not update rows which are not in df2**. How can i achieve that? I'm lost.
So my desirable result is:

```
UniqueKey ValueFix ValueChange
A            10      100
B            15      300
C            20      150
D            15      400
E            10      100
```

On my mind only solution where I show somehow transform df2 to dictionary with UniqueKey-ValuChange
And the with cycle go through ValueChange in df1 with condition like 'If row[Value_change] in dictionary then replace with value from dictionary.

But i have no idea how to do it with pandas

Comment: set the index using `df1=df1.set_index('UniqueKey')`  and do the same for df2, and then `df1.update(df2)`

Comment: `df2.set_index('UniqueKey').combine_first(df1.set_index('UniqueKey')).reset_index()`

Comment: But what to do if i want to update only values in column 'Value change'?

Comment: @Artem I still think my way would work. did you try?

Comment: @anky_91 I specified my question to avoid confusion. Your solution, as i guess will update all rows and columns in df1. I need update only specific values(in this case - zeros in column 'Value Change' in df1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should do it:

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
df1.loc[idx , 'ValueChange'] = df2[idx, 'ValueChange']
```

Output:

```
          ValueFix  ValueChange
UniqueKey                       
A                10          100
B                15          300
C                20          150
D                15          400
E                10          100
```

Comment: With this approach i get two errors: TypeError: unhashable type: 'RangeIndex' and pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: (RangeIndex(start=0, stop=52, step=1), 'Value Change')

Comment: After some fixing script works, but values don't change

Comment: Currently its raises KeyError because some of unique keys from df1 are not in df2

Comment: I modified my answer to fix a potential issue of creating new rows

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not doing exactly what's on my answer: `df2` not having keys from `df1` is not an issue at all, why do you get that error? what code are you actually running?

Comment: well, i simplified data of course but my task is the same. I had two enormous tables, for which i should perform script with described behaviour - update zeros based on key-value from another table. When i tried your solution python raised warning like "None of indexes [list on unique keys that in df1 but nor in df2] in <dataframe>. and values didn't change. So i had to go irrational way - i did df1.to_dict for both and checked values through cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to update your column in this way:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'UniqueKey': ['A', 'B','C','D','E'], 'ValueFix': [10,15,20,15,10], 'ValueChange': [100,0,150,0,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'UniqueKey': ['B', 'D'], 'ValueFix': [15,15], 'ValueChange': [300,400]})

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='UniqueKey', how='left')
df1.ValueChange = np.where(df1.UniqueKey.isin(df2.UniqueKey), merged_df.ValueChange_y, merged_df.ValueChange_x)
```

The output is

```
print(df1)
      UniqueKey  ValueFix  ValueChange
0         A        10        100.0
1         B        15        300.0
2         C        20        150.0
3         D        15        400.0
4         E        10        100.0
```

Comment: if UniqueKey is an index and not a regular column, you need to use df1.index.get_level_values('UniqueKey') instead of df1.UniqueKey

Comment: I reset index and tried your first suggestion and get ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects. I don't know why because my columns named identically. Will try now your second.

Comment: with second suggestion i get "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare"

Comment: Ok, I have corrected my answer. It happened because the where method expects row number and order to match.